# Как получить название .m3u8 файла в любое время стрима на twitch.tv

Tags: c#, python, twitch, m3u

Я знаю что если зайти на любой стрим через браузер и нажать сочетание клавиш `ctrl + shift + i` (для *google chrome*) будет открыто окошко *Network*. Там будет request с расширением `m3u8`.
Проблема в том что ссылка этого файла с расширением m3u8 при каждом запуске нового стрима разная. Каким еще образом можно получить ссылку на эти `m3u8` файлы, не используя браузер?

Не хочется каждый раз заходить и вручную выдергивать эту ссылку, надо это всё автоматизировать. Нужно написать скрипт который проверяет каждую минуту отправляются ли эти request'ы, соответственно если не отправляются, то стрим не запущен, в ином же случае мы получаем эту ссылку.

Пример выглядит вот [так](https://video-weaver.fra02.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/CqoEV0Pwkm8u5CHiPANdxTpVHmwE7kCKoL-7y9X0q3w9FWeCvyxTRLoYklvTP0DjLth-71oTezQl6GWZBsmqd13OfyImmutxeSV-Vf6sDFb1dsvEzMsDd8eWHf_hH-AB2WHVoyPJHsbuOE6DH7vBJkoarnOysKxT40qSOruWWT0bdkrJZpxmqThXGe7ZjwvmHCxDsMkOXjArojGIwzt76IOi41eFZlayhBvv-M-DWnf1Cpv9BgyoFA5s9BvZXVQtWGGeNATIiRi6XfPtbiJH0c-aenkAekG_xyi-g5MJbm4am40gA49H_qzNayAZohSSbxFTt2XYeYQo1pOOk37lnFOFsbsFGX-Rqd7xAO3RJVPGhApu5SvWMY2Idu3X2VLXBMpNNhTspRrr8Z_RWdKOpkVy6kxnxyggadnxC8yc0Pz6sC4o03pfGDGSEyHM-az0ZQ_L5dZndcGNnSYqUyP-Ie4K4S5-EBHdt5zIKjjNqK_4AD95aVUqL3XzDYXkafsc3-p1Lv9PYlDs84LfmlNjfLnjt_VymIejwUWFAFsMkhmOSuuXwql_Y6S1SNpvUsEeaYX0QZFIQTLn6NYcEDZUZZyFhsZafXJUdsFMWgb_cOEUe6YnXygA_la1p_XBtQbJCZ_JTWqiiRvCdKGZW8WsxzAWH_Uc9eXXMCFpnEdGXWm8YIkYiedavy3TgjwKHLnmSQkRSdxnkjUrj6ZsYaYDLUkiMUBBMKjAuLBqB0MSEJ-ikEH6WaS1JjteTgyl7JYaDIca9cXe_jGN1AS2RQ.m3u8)

```
https://video-weaver.fra02.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/CqoEV0Pwkm8u5CHiPANdxTpVHmwE7kCKoL-7y9X0q3w9FWeCvyxTRLoYklvTP0DjLth-71oTezQl6GWZBsmqd13OfyImmutxeSV-Vf6sDFb1dsvEzMsDd8eWHf_hH-AB2WHVoyPJHsbuOE6DH7vBJkoarnOysKxT40qSOruWWT0bdkrJZpxmqThXGe7ZjwvmHCxDsMkOXjArojGIwzt76IOi41eFZlayhBvv-M-DWnf1Cpv9BgyoFA5s9BvZXVQtWGGeNATIiRi6XfPtbiJH0c-aenkAekG_xyi-g5MJbm4am40gA49H_qzNayAZohSSbxFTt2XYeYQo1pOOk37lnFOFsbsFGX-Rqd7xAO3RJVPGhApu5SvWMY2Idu3X2VLXBMpNNhTspRrr8Z_RWdKOpkVy6kxnxyggadnxC8yc0Pz6sC4o03pfGDGSEyHM-az0ZQ_L5dZndcGNnSYqUyP-Ie4K4S5-EBHdt5zIKjjNqK_4AD95aVUqL3XzDYXkafsc3-p1Lv9PYlDs84LfmlNjfLnjt_VymIejwUWFAFsMkhmOSuuXwql_Y6S1SNpvUsEeaYX0QZFIQTLn6NYcEDZUZZyFhsZafXJUdsFMWgb_cOEUe6YnXygA_la1p_XBtQbJCZ_JTWqiiRvCdKGZW8WsxzAWH_Uc9eXXMCFpnEdGXWm8YIkYiedavy3TgjwKHLnmSQkRSdxnkjUrj6ZsYaYDLUkiMUBBMKjAuLBqB0MSEJ-ikEH6WaS1JjteTgyl7JYaDIca9cXe_jGN1AS2RQ.m3u8
```

Comment: А с помощью чего Вы, молодой человек, хотите сие дело автоматизировать? И в каком виде? Дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос)

Comment: В этом то и состоит вопрос. Я понятия не имею каким образом браузер получает данные об этих файлах. А как автоматизировать я уже написал, в моем представлении можно написать скрипт который получает эти данные каждую минуту. В точности я не знаю каким образом, поэтому и задаю данный вопрос.

Comment: Вот я как раз об этом: на чем скрипт писать собираетесь? От этого все же ответ зависит)

Comment: Скрипт на python

Comment: Другое дело) Добавил Вам в тэги язык, чтобы помощь пришла скорее)

Comment: Ну на самом деле, в моем случае не особо важно на каком языке программирования писать, если где-то есть возможность получать эти данные, то реализовать можно на чем угодно если постараться. Вывод все равно один: это ссылка на m3u8 файл, либо ёё отсутствие.

Comment: Не думаю, что если Вам предложат решение на условном Brainfuck, Вы сильно обрадуетесь :D Так что в тех случаях, когда Вам все равно, на чем реализовывать, просто добавляйте в тэги список приоритетных для Вас языков (либо же метку `любой язык`, если Вам действительно все равно)

Comment: Хорошо, добавлю еще парочку, спасибо за советы.

Comment: Но лучше все таки конкретные языки, так как здесь не так много сидит людей (вроде меня), которые листают общий поток вопросов. Большинство проверяет лишь обновления по интересующим их меткам, так что человек, который мог бы помочь Вам, попросту не увидит Вашего вопроса ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Да не за что ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Было бы за что, если бы я Вам с Вашей проблемой помог, но, увы, не знаю, что у `Twitch` творится, так что могу лишь посоветовать, как скорее найти того, кто знает ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, не надо учить нового пользователя плохому. Метки языка стоит использовать только когда вопрос специфичен для конкретного языка, а не только из-за того, что автор пишет код на данном языке. И уж тем более не стоит накидывать меток разных языков лишь бы побольше народу вопрос прочитало.

Comment: @Александр: Вы как-то исказили мой посыл. Я не говорю, мол, накидайте тысячу меток, чтобы вопрос поскорее заметили. Наоборот, необходимы лишь метки тех языков, на которые будет ориентировано решение. А зачем - я обосновал выше

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, не могу с вами согласиться. Метка языка нужна, если вопрос относится к языку. А то надоело уже по метке "питон" читать вопросы про апи телеграмма, апи вконтакта, апи твича...

Comment: @Александр: нет, ну смотрите, я повторюсь: положим, автору дадут ответ на каком-нибудь Lua, который он первый раз в жизни видит. Ему легче от этого станет? Сомневаюсь. Одно дело задавать вопросы про API (если я Вас правильно понял, и эти вопросы относятся только и только к API некого сервиса, а не к какой-нибудь библиотеке, с ним связанной), а другое - про весьма конкретную реализацию

Comment: youtube-dl может этим заниматься

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому интересно, то вопрос решился использованием программы streamlink для записи онлайн трансляций. Которая не спрашивает .m3u8